# OpenGL 2.0 on Windows 10 on VirtualBox on El Capitan

Tags: macos, windows, graphics, virtualbox

Some software running on Windows 10 requires me to have OpenGL 2.0.
I'm running Windows 10 in VirtualBox, which is on El Capitan.

How do I install OpenGL 2.0?

*Please explain as if speaking to a layman.* `:)`

Error message given by the software:

> Required OpenGL extensions: GL_VERSION_2_0, GL_ARB_framebuffer_object, GL_ARB_texture_compression, are unsupported. Please update your computer's graphics drivers or verify that your graphics card supports the listed features. If this error persists after updating the drivers, you will most likely need to upgrade your graphics card.

Comment: OGL 'base spec' is OGL 2.1, which pretty much every Mac [& Boot Camp] since OS X is capable of running... so, could you be more specific? See [Apple KB: Mac computers that use OpenCL and OpenGL graphics](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202823)

Comment: What do you mean by more specific? What info do you want? I'll post the error message given by the software right now, in case it give the specifics you are looking for.

Comment: error messages are good - they give clues...

Comment: OK, I've added it. Also, regarding your link, my computer is: MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014).

Comment: I'd see if you can get updated graphics drivers direct from [Intel](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/default.aspx?) for the Iris 5100 & see if those will install. As you aren't in Boot camp I can't think of another way.

Comment: Could such a method potentially seriously harm my computer?

Comment: I doubt it, really

Answer (score 3):

VirtualBox Guest Additions for Windows 8 or later no longer add the necessary registry entries to enable OpenGL support.

Based on comments in [No OpenGL Support for Windows 8](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12048) and related links I was able to craft the following Registry file to add the missing OpenGL keys...

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0000]
"OpenGLDriverName"="VBoxOGL.dll"
"OpenGLDriverNameWow"="VBoxOGL-x86.dll"
"OpenGLFlags"=dword:00000001
"OpenGLFlagsWow"=dword:00000001
"OpenGLVersion"=dword:00000001
"OpenGLVersionWow"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\OpenGLDrivers\MSOGL]
"DriverVersion"=dword:00000001
"Flags"=dword:00000001
"Version"=dword:00000001
"DLL"="VBoxOGL.dll"
```

Due to hardware detection that happens at various points there is proper order of doing this as well:

1. Enable 3D acceleration on your guest *before* powering it up to install Windows.
2. Install Windows 10.
3. Install VirtualBox guest additions and reboot.
4. Import the above Registry file and reboot.

Note that this is *limited* OpenGL support - it only enables things up to API Level OpenGL 2.1. Some things work fine, others not so much. e.g.: Blender 2.78 refused to start before this change, citing lack of OpenGL support, but afterwards it starts... and just displays a white window.

**Update 2017-03-04:**

Blender's all-white window issues were fixed by downloading their software-based OpenGL driver, ftp://ftp.blender.org/sergey/softwaregl/win64/opengl32.dll, and copying it into the folder `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender`

It obviously won't be performant like this but at least it's usable... which is important because a lot of Blender add-ons only work on Windows (e.g.: Bos FBX Importer/Exporter only works on win64 systems).

Comment: The update works with 2.79 even a year later

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a VNC client so you can connect from any android tablet or phone. Once you do this, you should then install MESS and run the BIOS package installer for PS4. From your android tablet, run the VNC viewer to go into Windows 10 and start ePSXe. From the configuration settings in ePSX, you should be able to select OpenGL as your video drivers. Select any game, and you're all set!

The graphics are incredibly smooth on the tablet. It's like holding a PS4 in your hands!

Comment: How does this help? The question was about OpenGL in Windows 10 in the VirtualBox.